# Favorite Questions and answers from third quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

Posted - [Highlights from 2019 – 3rd Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2019/10/highlights-from-2019-3rd-quarter/)

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2019 through September 30th 2019.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/07/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

> You really like the word "Also". – TheAsh

Answer (score 7):

I particularly enjoyed Laurel's (deeply unexpected) answer to this question about an obscure superhero figurine.

- [Weird blue and purple humanoid superhero keychain with "Z" chest emblem, X-eyes, and trident head](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212627/weird-blue-and-purple-humanoid-superhero-keychain-with-z-chest-emblem-x-eyes)

I thought my answer to this Truman Show question was pretty nice. It also gave me an excuse to go through the entire film frame-by-frame.

- [When does The Truman Show take place?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217565/when-does-the-truman-show-take-place)

This question/answer set proved amusing. Ryan Veeder performed some very nice statistical analysis and cryptography to come up with an answer, then found his answer proven by simply replacing the [Gobbledygook font](https://www.fonts.com/font/comicraft/gobbledygook) with the appropriate letters :-)

- [What language is Raven using for her attack in the new 52?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216683/what-language-is-raven-using-for-her-attack-in-the-new-52)